# Why am I getting a parse exception when I try to parse the current LocalDateTime

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to parse a `LocalDate` with a custom formatter but it is throwing following error. What am I doing wrong?

Error:

> // The local date time now value is 2019-09-19T14:42:23.837
>       java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-09-19T14:42:23.837' could not be parsed at index 10

Code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        LocalDateTime timeStamp = LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.now().toString(), formatter);
```

Comment: Because `"T"` is not `" "` most likely.

Comment: The question why you want to format a LocalDateTime to get LocalDateTime??

Comment: @YCF_L I am just looking to format the current date time to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS and following that get String value out of it via timeStamp.toString().

Comment: In this case  String timeStamp = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` cannot have a format, so cannot have a space instead of the `T` in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to `ISO_DATE_TIME` which gives you the "T"

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;

        LocalDateTime timeStamp=  LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.now().toString(),formatter);
        System.out.println(timeStamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong formatter pattern, you should use [ISO date-time formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME;
```