# How can i convert String to Date when it has "TRT" in it

Tags: java, date, datetime-format

```
String sDate = "06.08.2020" // 06 day 08 month 2020 is year
```

This is the date i  have in my txt file. I use them in JTable. To sort the table i convert them to date with this DateFormatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

And it does convert the string to date as this.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(sDate,formatter);
//The date : Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 TRT 2020
```

Now i need to convert it like the first date `06.08.2020`.
But i can't use *date* as input. Because i get it from JTable so i get it as *String*.

So i tryed this code.

```
String sDate1 = "Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 TRT 2020";// The date i get from JTable
LocalDate lastdate = LocalDate.parse(sDate1,formatter);
sDate1 = formatter.format(lastdate);
```

But i get an error as this `Text 'Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 TRT 2020' could not be parsed at index 0`.

So this cone not works fine : `LocalDate lastdate = LocalDate.parse(sDate1,formatter);`
I cant see where is  the problem.

Comment: **You should definitely stop using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`** – they're obsolete. Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: @MCEmperor i will check it now. Thanks for the tip sir.

Comment: I found the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime) to be a helpful overview for `java.time`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I suspect that your exception may come from code that you haven’t shown us and that you also don’t need.

Comment: @OleV.V. the error line is (parse) part. So i just cant convert the String to Date.

Comment: `String date = "06.08.2020";` = you have a String in `dd.MM.yyyy` format, and then you try to **parse** _that string_ `sdf1.parse(date)` using the format `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy` — I would _expect_ that to fail. The date-string that you are trying to parse is _not in the format_ that the parser expects.

Comment: Strings representing dates will sort correctly if they are in the form "yyyyMMdd" without having to convert them to actual dates or timestamps — `String sortableDateString = inputDateString.replaceAll("(\\d\\d)\\.(\\d\\d)\\.(\\d{4})", "$3$2$1");`

Comment: `sdf1.parse(date)` throws `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "06.08.2020"`, not the exception you quoted. With `sdf` instead `sdf1` it doesn’t throw any exception.

Comment: @OleV.V. i changed the post with java.time but still getting same error and i hope i explained my problem better now.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow related: [Why am I getting a parse exception when I try to parse the current LocalDateTime \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012504/why-am-i-getting-a-parse-exception-when-i-try-to-parse-the-current-localdatetime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Where your code failed:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf1=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
String dateStr = "06.08.2020";
sdf1.parse(dateStr);
```

As you can see, the pattern of the `SimpleDateFormat` and that of the `date` string do not match and therefore, this code will throw `ParseException`.

### How to make it work?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String dateStr = "06.08.2020";
Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);
```

You must have already got why it worked. It worked because the pattern of the `SimpleDateFormat` matches with that of the `dateStr` string.

### Can I format the `Date` object (i.e. `date`) into the original string?

Yes, just use the same format which you used to parse the original string as shown below:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
String dateStr = "06.08.2020";
Date date = sdf.parse(dateStr);

// Display in the default format
System.out.println(date);

// Format into the string
dateStr = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(dateStr);
```

### A piece of advice:

I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (package, `java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Using the modern date-time API:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
String dateStr = "06.08.2020";
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, formatter);

// Display in the default format
System.out.println(date);

// Format into the string
dateStr = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(dateStr);
```

### I don't see any difference using the legacy API and the modern API:

That's true for this simple example but when you will need to do complex operations using date and time, you will find the modern date-time API smart and clean while the legacy API complex and error-prone.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given date-time string
        String strDate = "Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 TRT 2020";

        // Replace TRT with standard time-zone string
        strDate = strDate.replace("TRT", "Europe/Istanbul");

        // Define formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");

        // Parse the date-time string into ZonedDateTime
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDate, formatter);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // If you wish, convert ZonedDateTime into LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-08-06T00:00+03:00[Europe/Istanbul]
2020-08-06T00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. I changed my code as your advice. But i still get the error. And now i explained more details. As i said before i cant use your *date* as you did. I have to get it as *String*. Convert it to *Date* and convert to *String* again. If i do as you did no problem. But when i try to get *Date* as *String*, i get teh error.

Comment: @Gresta - I've added an update which should fulfil your requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. The following code worked fine for me:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
      String date = "06.08.2020";
      Date date1 = sdf.parse(date);
      String result = sdf.format(date1);

      System.out.println("Date = " + result);
    }
}
```

**Output:** Date = 06.08.2020

That being said, if at all possible you should switch to the new `java.time.*` [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Comment: The problem is i cant get "date1" as a date. I can get it as String. When i try your code it works fine. But when i convert date1 to String then i try to parse it. I get "Unparseable date" error.

Comment: But my code gets date1 as a date. And then converts it to a string. If you can't reproduce it, then that means your input differs from what I used as input, it's the only way you'd get that error. If you literally copy my code as is, compile it and run it, with the same input, it should, and will, produce the same output.

Comment: as i said the code works fine. And i use same SimpleDateFormat for my all codes. The thing is, i get the date from the table. The user select the date. So i cant know what date i should convert. I get the Date as String from txt and convert it to Date to write to the JTable. After that i need the date. But as you know i cant get it as Date from JTable so i have to convert it. But i get the error i said.

Comment: @Gresta - you get a date that was selected by the user from a table, you get `dd.MM.yyyy` but _**you**_ are the one choosing `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"`to use in your SimpleDateFormat — you don't have to choose that format to get a sortable date, and it's especially pointless to include the timezone. And as _everyone_ is saying, if this is a new piece of code you're writing, use the `java.time.*` package instead.

Comment: @StephenP i understand what you said. Dont mind me if i explained wrong. I was trying to say, i cant get the input as a date. I have to get it as a String. And thats the different between the my code and JustAnotherDeveloper's code. And i will check the java.time.* right now. Thanks

Comment: @Gresta: My code uses a String as input. If you get it from a table, you can probably restrict the format in which the date must be entered in the table (or if it's retrieved from a database, you should know in which format it is stored), so there's no reason why not knowing your exact input should be a problem. Furthermore, if you get that error with the String you retrieve from the JTable, the problem is, as I predicted, that your input does not follow the pattern with which you've built your date formatter.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper now i edit the code with more detail. I understand what you said but i use same formatter for everything. But still getting the error.

Comment: @Gresta: I have literally copied your code into an online IDE and it works, you can check it here and see that it prints the date in the specified format: [https://jdoodle.com/ia/CK](https://jdoodle.com/ia/CK)

TRT is the timezone indicator for Turkey official time. There is definitely something in your input or your formatter that makes it not the input or formatter you are telling us you use, because that TRT does not magically appear out of nowhere.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper My code more complext then this. The formatter convert the date as not i want so i use multiple `DateTimeFormatter` and thats kinda fixed my problem. Thanks for the helps.